# Why does XPath not work for elements nested in hashtags

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am having some trouble with xpath. I have only worked with it for a bit, so I am not very familiar with it.

In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn9bh.png) I am trying to get the xpath of the button element. Normally, it would be `//button[@id='solver-button']`, but it does not work when I try to click on the element in Selenium Python:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='solver-button']"))).click()
```

Does anybody know why? I get the full XPath as `/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]//button` when I click "Copy full XPath", which does not work, and also `//*[@id="solver-button"]` when I click "Copy XPath", which does not work either (I tried using css selector, doesn't work either).

This is new to me, and I believe it to be because of the `#shadow-root (closed)` element, because I can access the div element above it without any issues.

Is there another way to get the xpath of that specific element or a workaround?

Answer (score -1):

Try to click through javascript.

```
ButtonEl=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='solver-button']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ButtonEl)
```

Comment: the question states that finding the element by xpath doesnt work (and it wont work due to it being inside shadow dom), so there is nothing to "click through javascript"